# HAML and Stripe in a form_for, I keep getting a compile error. Is there anything obviously wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I just switched my application over to rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9. I am also integrating Stripe through their API. Maybe this is causing problems?
I can't figure out for the life of me what the issue with this form is. It says the first error is on line 3 with the `else` statement (it's a compile error, full error detail below). All the indenting is consistent, I went through line-by-line and fixed it. Let me know if I should post more information, like my gemfile or something.

Here is the problematic **Form:**

```
=if 
    %h1 Sign up
=else
    %h1 Edit
=form_for(@user) do |f|
    =render "shared/error_messages", :target => @user
    =f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token
    %dl
        =if signed_in?
            %dt.field=f.label :avatar
            %dd.field=f.file_field :avatar
        %dt.field=f.label :name
        %dd.field=f.text_field :name
        %dt.field=f.label :email
        %dd.field=f.text_field :email
        =if @user.new_record?
            %dt.field=f.label :password
            %dd.field=f.password_field :password
        =if @user.stripe_card_token.present?
            %p Credit card has been provided.
        =else
            %div.field
                =label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number"
                =text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name:nil
            %div.field
                =label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)"
                =text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name:nil
            %div.field
                =label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
                =select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}
                =select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}
            %div#stripe_error
                %noscript JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.
    .actions
        =f.submit((defined?(editing) ? "Update" : "Sign Up"))
```

**Here is the error:**

```
compile error
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected kELSE
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:23: syntax error, unexpected kELSE
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:25: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
...d_tag :card_number, nil, name:nil
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:27: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
...eld_tag :card_code, nil, name:nil
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:30: odd number list for Hash
...month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_...
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:30: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
...month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_...
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:30: odd number list for Hash
...d_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:30: Can't assign to nil
...th_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:30: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
...umbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}
                              ^
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:30: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
/Users/brianjoseff/rails_projects/groupie/app/views/users/_form.html.haml:37: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
...Util.html_safe(_erbout);ensure;@haml_buffer = @haml_buffer.u...
                              ^
```

Thanks all

**UPDATE 1...new form without javascript array notation:**

```
=if 
    %h1 Sign up
=else
    %h1 Edit
=form_for(@user) do |f|
    =render "shared/error_messages", :target => @user
    =f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token
    %dl
        =if signed_in?
            %dt.field=f.label :avatar
            %dd.field=f.file_field :avatar
        %dt.field=f.label :name
        %dd.field=f.text_field :name
        %dt.field=f.label :email
        %dd.field=f.text_field :email
        =if @user.new_record?
            %dt.field=f.label :password
            %dd.field=f.password_field :password
        =if @user.stripe_card_token.present?
            %p Credit card has been provided.
        =else
            %div.field
                =label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number"
                =text_field_tag :card_number, :name =>  nil
            %div.field
                =label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)"
                =text_field_tag :card_code, :name   => nil
            %div.field
                =label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
                =select_month nil, {:add_month_numbers => true}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_month"}
                =select_year nil, {:start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year+15}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_year"}
            %div#stripe_error
                %noscript JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.
    .actions
    =f.submit((defined?(editing) ? "Update" : "Sign Up"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## = statements

You're using Javascript array notation in HAML. HAML uses Ruby to evaluate the =(expression):

So this is wrong:

```
= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}
```

should be:

```
= select_month nil, { :add_month_numbers => true}, { :name => nil, id => "card_month" }
```

## Else statements

The code lines don't produce output, so use - rather than =

```
- if 
    %h1 Sign up
- else
    %h1 Edit
```

Comment: Ok, the amount of errors has diminished, but I still get the `compile error`...`syntax error, unexpected kELSE` on line three. I have edited the question to include the edited form, taking out the javascript array notation

Comment: updated answer - the mustache is a once a year thing for movember (not allowed to keep it into December)

Comment: ah, that does the trick, for some reason I was under the false impression that in rails 3.1 one should use equal signs for everything in haml. Attention to detail is not my strong suit, unfortunately. thakns for the help

Comment: Nah, they really only changed the way that form_tag worked - it was inconsistent before.

Comment: damn the programming gods, pulling the wool over my eyes every step of the way. I feel like even RoR, which I hear is the easiest of them all, has a high barrier to entry, i.e. if you want to be good and deploy something worthwhile, you have to be some kind of savant.

Comment: The other thing I've just found out - your original hash notation was correct - e.g. in Ruby 1.9 - { notice: 'hello' } and { :notice => 'hello' } are the same

Comment: ok great, thanks for the due diligence. maybe someone down the line will find this helpful